# Вывести pointer через main если он в другой функции

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите, как вывести адрес или значение `pointer` через `main` и не через `printf`?

```
void ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
    *nbr = 42;
    return ;
}
```

У меня есть функция в которой хранится pointer, это ячейка памяти в которой храниться число 42. А я хочу с помощью другой функции main вывести число 42 на экран консоли.

Comment: `*nbr = 42;` вот за это не люблю С++.

Comment: О чем речь вообще? Какой еще `pointer`? И что значит "через `main` и не через `printf`"? (Последнее - это вообще что-то из области "шел дождь и два студента").

Comment: Если функция вызывается из `main`, можно просто вернуть указатель через `return` (соответственно, нужно поменять для функции тип возвращаемого значения)

Answer (score 1):

Если в main нет никаких зацепок за этот указатель, то придётся объявить глобальный указатель, которому присвоить этот nbr в функции. Таким образом получится два указателя на одну область память и можно будет в main использовать один из них - глобальный.

А вообще не понятно к чему так код запутывать... Неужели нельзя в функции предусмотреть необходимые операции с этим указателем?

Answer (score 0):

```
int * ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
    *nbr = 42;
    return nbr;
}

int main()
{
int * a = ft_ft(nbr);
cout << (*a);
}
```